# Running Clonezilla on an old PC without USB and CD boot

Tags: clonezilla

I need to run Clonezilla on an old PC (circa 1997) which has no USB ports, has a CD drive, but its bios cannot boot from it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

For a machine of that age, you should be able to set BIOS to start from CD. I recall doing this.

Start in BIOS, reset BIOS to start first from CD, second from the Hard Drive.

If there is a CD in the drive, it should start from it. If no CD, the drive will whirr a bit and then the hard drive will start.

Save changes, restart and test.

Another possibility is starting from a floppy disk drive. Without USB, you need a bus connected floppy drive.

You can put this string in Autoexec.bat

> A:\MSCDEX /D:IBMCD100 /M:10

(or whatever CD drive is)

Then in Config.sys

> DEVICE=A:\HIMEM.SYS
>
> DOS=HIGH
>
> DEVICE=A:\IBMIDECD.SYS /D:IBMCD100

You need the appropriate programs to run for your computer.

Boot from CD or boot from Floppy drive are your only hopes. I do not think FileZilla will fit on a floppy drive.

A machine this old is a 16-bit DOS machine. You also want to make sure CloneZilla will run once you get going. I am not exactly sure why you are trying to use DOS or a DOS system to run CloneZilla.

Have you tried looking for a different way to clone this old drive?  Consider using a different computer to clone the old drive.

Good luck

Comment: I am positive that the BIOS does not support CD boot. It is able to boot from the floppy and harddrive and I can naturally swap the order of these, but I cannot add the CD drive into the sequence. FYI, this is an Award BIOS PI-5XTP4.

Comment: I added known working Autoexec and Config statements for starting a CD after starting with a Floppy drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no ability to boot from CD or USB, then you will have to remove the drive.  You can install it in a more modern computer, or attach it to a computer with a SATA/IDE to USB [adapter](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=sata%20ide%20usb%20adapter&crid=5WOJ0Y5TRMCR&sprefix=sata%20ide%20usb%20%2Caps%2C185&ref=nb_sb_ss_ts-doa-p_1_13).